# Android texSubImage2D - is there different behaviour on different devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es

When calling `texSubImage2D`, I seem to be getting the bitmap I pass in positioned by its center on a Samsung Galaxy S3 / Galaxy Note 2, and by its top-left on a Samsung Galaxy S2.

It's making my textures totally wonky on the S3 / Galaxy Note 2.

Can someone confirm that there is indeed this difference in how this method offsets the bitmap, between these devices?

How do I ensure consistent behavior for texSubImage2D across all devices?

Comment: The function at least *should* be consistent across devices. So it might be much more helpful to see your actual code and what *you* might be doing wrong (if anything).

Comment: @Christian Rau, are you getting the same behavior for this method on Galaxy S2 and S3?

Comment: I don't get any behaviour on anything.

Answer (score 3):

texSubImage2D behaves consistently, I'm guessing that you are loading textures from resources and they are upscaled on note 2 / S3 (both are xhdpi devices) when compared to S2 (hdpi), and you probably use fixed size texture hence a difference.

Comment: But this doesn't happen on the S4, despite it being an xhdpi device. I'm not loading textures from resources, I'm drawing them straight to a `Bitmap` via a `Canvas`'s `draw...` methods and then simply uploading it to the GPU via `GLUtils.texSubImage2D`.

Comment: S4 is xxhdpi device (so there is a density difference as well), post some code then (first of all how you create you bitmap, are dimensions hardcoded etc). I can assure you that glTexSubImage2D works correctly so problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I wasn't talking about calling `glTexSubImage2D` directly, but `GLUtils.texSubImage2D`. Have you tested this method across S2 and S3 using the way I've described? I'm creating each Bitmap to upload via `Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)` and then drawing to it via `new Canvas(bitmap).draw...` methods - the drawing appears fine in all cases, only the offset is different (positioned by its top-left on S2 & S4, but by its center on S3) when I then call `GLUtils.texSubImage2D`.

Comment: I'm using GLUtils.texSubImage2D in my game and it works across all devices, so I'm 100% sure that problems lies somewhere else (maybe in drawing code itself?), it's really hard to guess given so vague info.